# Numpy expand bitmap into bitmap of bitmaps

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array representing a bitmap, and I would like to expand it into a vector of vectors where each entry has the value of the original bitmap at that position repeated n times.

Let me make an example to explain what I mean:

```py
n = 2
original = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

wanted = [
    [0, 0],
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [0, 0]
]
```

Obviously I could do it with a loop over the array, but I would really (really) like it to be fast, so I am hoping to use numpy methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use function zip

```
wanted = list(zip(*[original] * n))
```

or use numpy.dstack

```
wanted = np.dstack([original] * n)
```